# Populate DataGrid from Mysql Database

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview, datagrid

First of all I'm new with C# and Visual Studio.
I followed a tutorial on how to populate DataGridView from MySql table.
I checked multiple times for copying mistakes but I didn't find any.
The code is this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace DataGridMain
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private string server;
        private string database;
        private string uid;
        private string password;
        private MySqlConnection connection;
        private MySqlDataAdapter mySqlDataAdapter;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {  
         server = "localhost";
         database = "elphoapp";
         uid = "username";
         password = "password";
         string connectionString;
         connectionString = "SERVER=" + server + ";" + "DATABASE=" + database + ";" + "UID=" + uid + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + password + ";";

    connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);

    if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
    {
        mySqlDataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter("select * from users", connection);
        DataSet DS = new DataSet();
        mySqlDataAdapter.Fill(DS);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = DS.Tables[0];
        this.CloseConnection();
    }


        }

private bool OpenConnection()
{
    try
    {
        connection.Open();
        return true;
    }
    catch (MySqlException ex)
    {
        switch (ex.Number)
        {
            case 0:
                MessageBox.Show("Cannot connect to server. Contact administrator");
                break;
            case 1045:
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid username/password, please try again");
                break;
            default:
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                break;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
        private bool CloseConnection()
{
    try
    {
        connection.Close();
        return true;
    }
    catch (MySqlException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        return false;
    }
}
    }
    }
```

I can't seem to find a problem and no error is displaying.

Answer (score 0):

As you are new to Visual Studio, my advice is the first thing you must learn is debugging. It will save you a lot of times. In this case, put a breakpoint in your form_load and run the code step by step. You can that way see what is happening, and inspect all the variables. I'm saying this because i can't see any error in your code, so probably you are not even connecting to the database. Debugging your code you may see why

Comment: Oh guess what. Debug.WriteLine doesn't work either.
No matter where i put it just doesn't work. No error again and nothing is debugging.
I guess C programming languages are one of a kind...

Answer (score 0):

Ok i figured it out!
All i had to do was to call Form1_Load from inside the Form1() function.
Everything seems to be working fine at the moment.
Thanks, C# is full of damn surprises....

Comment: Hmm...is your project of type "Console application"? If it is, obviously Form_Load wouldn't be called, because it is a Windows Forms event handler.